# Eclipse intro/welcome page definition with content attribute does not find the file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

In my plugin/RCP I have defined my own contributions to Eclipse universal intro with page definitions inside the toplevel xml (the one pointed to by the "config" attribute to the "configExtension" element of the org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension extension point), which works.

However, I'd like to split out the page definitions to separate files for simpler editing and managing.

So I start out with (in my intro/introcontent.xml):

```
<page id="myfirststeps" style="$theme$/html/firststeps.css" style-id="page">
    <!-- Page content here -->
</page>
```

And this works. The intro displays the page content correctly. Then I move the page content to firststeps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<introContent>
    <page id="myfirststeps" style="$theme$/html/firststeps.css" style-id="page">
        <!-- Page content here -->
    </page>
</introcontent>
```

and change the toplevel xml to say:

```
<page id="myfirststeps" content="intro/firststeps.xml" />
```

does not work. Running this creates a "File not found" exception, and the file indicated is pointing into the Eclipse installation (like "C:\Program Files\Eclipse") and not, as I would have expected into my plugin. And sure enough, if I copy my xml-file there it finds it.

Any pointers? Is there some trick about the content attribute and how it resolves the path to the file?

Or is there a way to specify a path to the plugin directory in the content attribute?

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the solution was simple. The file reference in the content attribute is relative to the referencing xml-file, *not* relative to the plugin-root.

So all I had to do was to remove the "intro"-part of the path. From

```
<page id="myfirststeps" content="intro/firststeps.xml" />
```

to

```
<page id="myfirststeps" content="firststeps.xml" />
```

And all is well.